# Possible to access $this from include()'d file in PHP class?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, this

I'm working on a WordPress Widget and the examples all have huge HTML/PHP chunks intermixed and it is impossible to read, so in the interest of trying to clean stuff up I'd like to move all of the HTML rendering to a separate PHP file that will be `include()`'d.

The trick to this is, the file I include doesn't appear to have access to `$this` and I'm unsure how to fix that.

**widget.php**

```
class Preorder extends WP_Widget {
    ...
    function form() {
        include('form.php');
    }
}
```

**form.php**

```
<p>
   <?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>
</p>
```

Which results in `[31-Aug-2011 19:59:19] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_field_id() on a non-object in ...` so clearly `$this` doesn't come along for free. I've tried aliasing `$this` to another variable & even just for fun using the `global` keyword without success.

Hopefully I missed something easy.

Comment: That code should work. If the code is exactly as shown above, `$this` would be accessible in form.php. Something else is probably going on somewhere else.

Comment: Agree with mfonda, the above code should work. I do the exact same thing in many projects.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check guys, figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that I was iterating over the directory & `include`-ing every .php file, renamed form.php to form.tmpl and appears to work.

Durr.