# "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context" when using require - PHP

Tags: php, this

I have read a lot of similar questions and answers but none seems to address my situation.

CLASS A

```
class A{


 public function walk() {
     ...
 }

 public function dance() {
     require 'dance.php';    
 }
}
```

Now inside of `dance.php`, I have

`$this->walk();`

And I get this error:
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Please help. Is it that I cannot use $this inside a required file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have testet it in a clean environment and it works fine for me.

I assume that you maybe include dance.php somewhere else in your code where you are not in object context.

Please take also a look at [Possible to access $this from include()'d file in PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262705/possible-to-access-this-from-included-file-in-php-class) which is maybe a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks. I am writing a WordPress plugin and thought it's a PHP problem. Will take a closer look to solve the problem now that I know it's not a PHP issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it, it should work (PHP 5.6).

In my `dance.php` is just `<?php $this->walk();` and the remote method is called. The error must be somewhere else. Looks like you import the file somewhere else where you are not in object context.

---

Probably you should use traits. Traits enable to build logic and keep them separate to specific classes.

```
trait dance
{
    public function dance()
    {
        $this->walk();
    }
}

class A
{
    use dance;

    public function walk()
    {
        echo 'go forward';
    }
}

(new A())->dance();
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/g1Ybd

Comment: Is there also an answer to the question asked? =)

Comment: Just added a test ;)

Comment: We just posted nearly the same thing, at the same time :D

Comment: @copynpaste Thanks for the test. It's a WordPress Plugin environment. Thought it's a PHP issue. Will take a closer look