# PHP class includes a file, but that file cannot access the class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, include

I have a php class that uses "include" to load some html and php from a file. Within that file I want to access the class object that included the file, but I keep getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function makeSizesSelect() on a non-object ..."

I've tried both include and require, I've tried declaring globals, I've tried everything I can think of and everything I've so far found on SO. Nothing seems to allow the file I include to have php code access the object that included it.

Any ideas?

Here's a few snippets ...

The class file:

```
class cdf {
   public $version = 001;

   public function cdf_shortcode( $atts,$content ) 
   {
      $this->slog( 2,"shortcode() case: show" );
      require( 'templates/container.php' );
   }
}
```

And the required file container.php contains the following (amongst other stuff):

```
<?php 
    echo "version = ".$this->version;
?>
```

I then try to use the object:

```
$cdf = new cdf();
$cdf->cdf_shortcode( null, null);
```

The line $this->slog( 2,"shortcode() case: show" ) works. It runs that function (which I haven't included in this snippet) just fine. But then the file I require (or include) cannot use $this to access the object. I'm at a loss. :-(

All I want to do is access within the included file, the variables and methods in the class that included the file ...

Sorry, some added information. I'm not sure if this makes any difference. The code above is all part of a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Including a file is not enough, you need to instanciate your class.

Comment: because you don't have created any object to access your class, after include create object of class like $obj=new cdf(); then access member function like $obj->cdf_shortcode( '','' )

Comment: My apologies. The class is obviously instantiated, and the object exists. As I said, the first line in the shortcode function works. That wouldn't be the case if I hadn't instantiated the object.

Answer (score 1):

In the file you included you need to instantiate the class.

```
<?php
$yourClass = new cdf();
echo "version = ".$yourClass->version;
?>
```

When you want to access a function in a class, you need to instantiate the class first otherwise you wont have access to anything inside of it.

Also make sure the file you are including wont be included anywhere else where the class `cdf` doesn't exist because that will result in an error.

The variable `$this` can only access methods, variables, etc. only if they are in the same object.

Update based on your answer that seems to have worked:

Example.php

```
<?php
echo $this->returnString();
echo $this->randomVariable;
```

File.php

```
<?php
class IncludedClass
{
    public $randomVariable = 123;
    public function returnString()
    {
        return "some random string";
    }
    public function meh()
    {
        require_once('Example.php');
    }
}
$meh = new IncludedClass();
$meh->meh();
```

Comment: But this is where I am at a loss. I instantiate the object, then use it. The included file, to my way of thinking, is inserting additional code into the method of the class, and that's why I'm expecting $this to work, as it does in the line before the include().

Comment: By using `$this->version;` the code assumes you're trying to access the variable that is in the same class as `echo "version = ".$this->version;`. Replace `$this` with the name of the object where you instantiated the class. `$yourClass` in my example.

Comment: I just tried your solution, adding $mycdf = new cdf(); echo "version = ".$mycdf->version; I still get an error: Fatal error: Class 'cdf' not found.

Comment: Sorry Arthur, your example is pretty much the reverse of my situation. You have the class defined in the external file that is being included. That is not my problem.

My class is including another file that has more code in it. And in that code in the extra file I want to access variable and methods in the class that included the file. See my code above again.

Comment: @CraigD Updated the answer again. It's working fine for me.

Comment: It may very well be working for you. It should. But it's not the problem I'm having. Take a look at my code again. My include()/require() is inside a method in the class. That seems to be the source of the problem. Your code is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Curious issue with a curious solution. I finally found the answer over here:

[Possible to access $this from include()'d file in PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262705/possible-to-access-this-from-included-file-in-php-class?rq=1)

I tried all the obvious solutions this poster tried (globals, casting to another variable, etc) with the same lack of success. Turns out, just changing the file extension from .php to .tmpl fixed the issue, and my included file can now access the object that included it. Weird. (Of course, the downside now is that my IDE doesn't colour my code for me. :-( )

Thanks for your suggestions guys.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was on your side, it seems to be working fine for me. I'll update my answer again. Also I am not sure why you would want to include a file inside of a method.